# How can I make a JTable cell do different things on single-click than on double-click?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using an editable `JTable` that contains a column named Subject. When the first row is empty and the user clicks on a subject cell to add new task, by default, the user has to click twice to make the cell editable. I want to make it editable on single-click and have it open another form on double-click. I have tried `MouseListener` but have not been able to solve it. Is there a way to solve this problem? If so, what is it?

My code:

```
class mouseRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    JLabel lblcell = new JLabel();

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        ttable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                selrow = ttable.getSelectedRow();
                selcol = ttable.getSelectedColumn();

                if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    if(selrow == 0) {
                        lblcell.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return lblcell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the one-click to edit, you could try the 'setClickCountToStart()' method of the celleditor used in your jtable.

Comment: possible if the editor is of type DefaultCellEditor (which those registered by default are)

Comment: I am able to edit the cell on mouse's one click and able to open another form on mouse's double click.But the problem is:It works if I use right click(twice) to open another form.I want to open another form by using left click(twice) and edit the cell on single left mouse click.Used the above pasted code.How can I use left mouse's double click to open form?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to create a custom CellEditor like this one and set it with `setCellEditor()`

```
public class MyTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject evt) {
        if (evt instanceof MouseEvent) {
            int clickCount;

            // For single-click activation
            clickCount = 1;

            // For double-click activation
            clickCount = 2;

            // For triple-click activation
            clickCount = 3;

            return ((MouseEvent)evt).getClickCount() >= clickCount;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MouseListener` is the way to go for capturing double clicks on a row.  It should work fine.

As far as one-click to edit, you might want to select rows using a `MouseMotionListener` and let the JTable take the single-click to edit.  Another option might be to use a MouseListener to detect the cell that was clicked, but that is getting a little messy.

Comment: Thanks.. Let me try of MouseMotionListener.But I didnt get how to make JTable editable only by single click. Let me try again.